# Possible to override "Pin" functionality of Windows 7 Jump List Item? Or multiple commands on a single line

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, jump-list

I've started adding JumpLists to my programs and know how to "talk back" using a single instance of my program, but I was wondering if it is possible to override the Pin functionality or otherwise add two commands to a single line?

I want to have an "Open location" (main click) or "Remove location" option, and was hoping to be able to override the Pin icon to act as the "remove".

I know I could do it by making twice as many items and having half of them as "remove" and half as "open", but it would really clean up the UI / List if they could be on a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. Looking at both the [managed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd985741.aspx) and [unmanaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378460(v=VS.85).aspx#jump_lists) API's it's pretty clear that a JumpList is a collection of JumpItem and a JumpItem (or really, a JumpTask or JumpPath) can only take a single path with additional arguments. To override the JumpItem click handler you'd need access to methods that are not exposed by Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping I was just missing something and there was a way to do it, seems like a missed opportunity by Microsoft to make the jump lists extra useful

Comment: @John This software http://www.1upindustries.com/bins/ manipulates the taskbar behavior - I don't know how it was done (probably entirely replaces default taskbar behavior) and I doubt it was written in C#, but there may be some hope. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Win7 jumplists before, but is there an event you can catch if users "unpin" an item? If so, you could catch that event, do the necessary operations, and re-add the item to the jumplist... A bit of a workaround, but it'd do what you want.

Otherwise, just change the text and functionality of a list item once it's clicked (from "Open location" to "Remove location" if the user opened a location and vice versa). You could keep a boolean or something for each item to distinguish the current state.

Comment: Yeah thats what I was looking for, but it doesn't appear to have that functionality anywhere... it looks like the jump lists are all handled by windows and have no direct interaction with your program at all, hence the need for a "single" instance version of your program to have the list clicks perform functions (like opening a new tab in IE). So looks like there isn't any way to do this which is a shame :(